# Time Speed Distance Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A boy leaves for school at 10:40 a.m. He spends 5 hrs in school and comes back at 5:20 pm on the same day. He travels at a constant speed of 1.4 km/hr. How far away is his school?

Comment: What have you tried? You could start by figuring out the travel time to school.

Comment: If you think about it, there are 2 times when he has to travel to and from school, so there is a variable of $2x$.

Comment: @JosephHulme, he doesn't finish at $5:20\space pm$, he reaches back at home by $5:20\space pm$

Comment: @DevanshKamra Sorry, I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the distance from his school to home be $x$ metres, hence the time taken for him to reach to school from home is $t=\dfrac{3x}{70}$ minutes.

Therefore the total time spent in journey would be $2t$ minutes and the total time between him leaving home and him coming back home would be $2t+300$ minutes.

Leaving time$\rightarrow10:40\space am$

Returning time$\rightarrow5:20\space pm$

$\therefore$ Total time spent$\rightarrow 400\space minutes$
$$400=2t+300$$
$$t=50=\dfrac{3x}{70}$$
$$x=\dfrac{3500}{3}=1166.\overline 6$$
Hence his school was $1.16\space km$ away from his home
.

Answer (score -1):

No need for "algebra" as such. Just take away the time he spends at school. If he didn't spend any time at school and started back immediately after arriving, he'd reach home at $12:20 \ $pm, which is $100 \ $ min after he'd started. That's a round trip, so a one way trip would've taken $50 \ $min, which makes the distance $1.4 \times \frac{50}{60} = \frac76 \ $km.